# How to make on click on input search in Js?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, razor, onclick

So I have this code

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.btn-create-tournament', function () {

    var title = $(".create-tournament-title").val();
    var format = $(".create-tournament-format").val();
    var sport = $(".create-tournament-sport").val();
    var prize = $(".create-tournament-prize").val();
    var date = $(".create-tournament-date").val();
    var location = $(".create-tournament-location").val();
    var teams = $(".create-tournament-teams").val();

    $.post('/Tournament/Create', {
        title: title,
        format: format,
        sport: sport,
        prize: prize,
        date: date,
        location: location,
        teams: teams
    }, function (response) {
        if (response > 0) {
            window.location.href = "/Tournament/Details/" + response;
        }
    })

}).on('input', '.search-teams', function () {
    var query = this.value;
    $.get('/Teams/Search', { name: query }, function (response) {

        $('.search-team-results').html($(response).find('.team-results-search').html());

    })




})
```

and then I call the input function here

```
@model List<TeamViewModel>

<div class="search-team-results">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div>
            <label class="team-results-search" data-team-id="@item.Id">@item.Name</label>
            
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

and finally it goes there

```
<h6>Players</h6>

                                    <div class="form-outline">
                                        <input class="search-teams" type="search" placeholder="Type query" aria-label="Search" />
                                        <div class="search-team-results">
                                            
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

so I'm searching in a input field for the teams but they are showing below the field as label only and my question is how to make a script to actually add them to my list which is in my viewmodel?

Comment: Note: the `label` HTML element should only be used for labeling form elements, not just for plain text. For plain text, use a `p` or other text element.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(response).find('.team-results-search').html()
```

will only get you the inner html (only text in this case) of the first label in the result list. To get the whole list use

```
$(response).find('.search-team-results').html()
```

Comment: For some reason when I type it with .team-results-search it works but when I type .search-team-results it doesn't. My question actually was when the result is shown how to make a script to take the value from the input field and on click to add it to the list which is in my viewmodel?